# Temporarily suspend bash_history on a given shell?

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there a way to temporarily suspend history tracking in bash, so as to enter a sort of "incognito" mode? I'm entering stuff into my terminal that I don't want recorded, sensitive financial info.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

This will prevent bash from saving any new history when exiting the shell:

```bash
unset HISTFILE
```

Specifically, according to `man bash`:

> If HISTFILE is unset, or if the history file is unwritable, the history is not saved.

Note that if you re-set `HISTFILE`, history will be saved normally. This only affects the moment the shell session ends.

Alternatively, if you want to toggle it off and then back on again during a session, it may be easier to use [`set`](https://ss64.com/bash/set.html):

```bash
set +o history # temporarily turn off history

# commands here won't be saved

set -o history # turn it back on
```

Comment: The value of `HISTFILE` is only checked when bash exits, so the first method doesn't work as is (if you restore the value, the command will be saved). `set +o history` does work as directed.

Comment: Thanks, excellent. I'll use `set +o history` and `set -o history` to toggle back and forth when I'm doing secret stuff ;)

Comment: `unset HISTFILE` does not work.

`set -/+o history` works like a charm! thanks

Comment: As a tip if you put a space before command (start the command with a space) it will not be recorded in  your history, and up/down arrow keys will not show it either.

Comment: This won't work in zsh btw

Comment: Only unsetting  HISTFILE does not erase the command list in memory (try `history` to see it). If additionally you do `HISTSIZE=0` the list gets erased and no command could be stored to file (as no command is remembered).

Comment: anybody knows why +o ? where can I read documentation about this future?

Comment: @Tebe run `help set`

Comment: Got it, but hhis is still strange that + disables and - enables history

Comment: @Tebe it mentions the use of ‘+’ to disable the option at the very bottom. Granted it’s weird that a plus disables but they really had no choice since the dash-option has historically been used to enable an option.

Answer (score 49):

Using bash, set `HISTCONTROL="ignorespace"` and precede with space any command you do not wish to be recorded in history. In case you forgot to take any measures, there is also `history -d <number>` for deleting a specific entry or `history -c` for clearing the entire command history.

Comment: Put the HISTCONTROL="ignorespace" into ./~bashrc file, then run the source ~/.bashrc command.

Comment: For users of *zsh* 

`setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE         # Don't record an entry starting with a space.`

Answer (score 30):

Make sure that `HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace`. You'll probably want to add `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` (or `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace` or something) to your `~/.bashrc`. Then any command line that begins with a space is omitted from the history.

Another possibility is to start a new bash session that doesn't save its history.

```
$ bash
$ unset HISTFILE
$ sooper-sekret-command
$ exit
$ #back in the parent shell
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need to avoid storing several commands and you still want to use up arrow to access previous commands, use:

```
$ bash                        # open a new session.
$ unset HISTFILE              # avoid recording commands to file.
$ commands not recorded
.
.
$ exit
$
```

---

There are four ways (levels) to control how commands are stored.

1. The first and simplest is to use `ignorespace` (or ignoreboth):

   ```
   $ HISTCONTROL="ignorespace${HISTCONTROL:+:$HISTCONTROL}"
   ```

   That will allow to use an space before the commands that you want to avoid being recorded in the memory list of `history`. And, in consequence, as there is no command recorded in memory that could be sent to file, will also avoid **one** command to be sent to the file listed in `$HISFILE`.
2. Avoid recording commands to the file in `$HISTFILE`:

   ```
   $ unset HISTFILE
   ```

   > If unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.

   Null `HISTFILE=''` and/or set to `HISTFILE=/dev/null` works to the same effect.
   Understand that commands are still being recorded to the memory list , try the `history` command, or the up arrow.

   Warning: if HISTFILE is reset before the shell exists, all what has been recorded in memory could be written to the file anyway.
3. Avoid recording **new** commands to the history list in memory.
   And, as not being in memory, can not be recorded to file.

   ```
   $ shopt -ou history              # or set +o history
   ```

   Re-enable with `shopt -os history` (or `set -o history`)
4. Remove all commands from to the history list in memory:

   ```
   $ HISTSIZE=0
   ```

   All commands get erased (from memory) and therefore nothing could be stored to file, of course, until the variable is set again to some valid numeric value.

Comment: // , This covers all the answers except the answer from @Ambrose in one convenient page. Way to go, @Isaac. Would you be willing to add a link or two to the docs for this? Pretty sure `man history` isn't going to cut it for most of us.

Comment: @NathanBasanese Expanded. Better?

Comment: // , Yes! Would I be correct in assuming that these come from the [Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) and [Shopt Built-in docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)?

Comment: // , Also, while I was reading [the Bash Variables documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html), I came across `HISTIGNORE`, which `subsumes` the function of `HISTCONTROL`.

Comment: (Assuming you are using linux): What happens if you execute the command `LESS=+'/^ *HISTI' man bash` (isn't that the "manual pages"?). @NathanBasanese

Comment: No, HISTCONTROL has a different goal than HISTIGNORE.Yes, those pages are relevant to history in bash, however, the `man bash` is more up to date. @NathanBasanese

Comment: If running bash, the simple command `help shopt` should help you.@NathanBasanese

Answer (score 3):

There is one simple way to turn off the history, so commands won't be stored in the `.bash_history` file.

You have to put the whitespace or tab space in front of any command, so that command won't be stored in the history. For example:

```
$ ls 
print the list of file 
$ history 
ls
history

$  pwd
print the current  working directory 
$ history 
ls
history
```

The `pwd` command will not get store in the history, because it has whitespace in the front.

Comment: This does not work; Bash complains that '-' or '-history', or other hyphenated commands cannot be found.

Comment: This wont work unless HISTCONTROL="ignorespace" is set as in forcefsck's response

Answer (score 2):

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

That is my goto way.  Just in case the unset HISTORY/HISTFILE/HISTCONTROL, etc... doesn't work, exporting it to /dev/null has always worked for me.

Comment: For temporarily suspending history? This didn't work for me as a regular command. Subsequent commands were logged to history. Are you calling this in .bash_profile or a script? `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`

Answer (score 0):

To take SiegeX's answer a bit further and really make this into incognito mode...

Disclaimer: title stuff will probably on work on gnome-terminal. it was only tested in Linux Mint 19.3 / Gnome Terminal 3.28.1 because i'm lazy.

Add the following to your `~/.bash_functions` (this assumes you are importing it via your `.bashrc` / `.profile` etc):

```
function setGnomeTerminalTitle() {
    local NEW_TITLE="$1";
    PS1="\[\e]0;${NEW_TITLE}\a\]\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]";
}
```

Then add the following to your `~/.bash_aliases` (again this assumes you are importing it via your `.bashrc` / `.profile` etc):

```
alias title="setGnomeTerminalTitle";
alias hist='history'
alias histoff="setGnomeTerminalTitle 'Incognito Window' && set +o history"
alias histon="setGnomeTerminalTitle \"$USER@$HOSTNAME:\${PWD//\${HOME//\\//\\\\\\/}/\\~}\" && set -o history"
```

EDIT: to explain the histon title stuff - normally the window title in gnome-terminal is "$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD}" except that if you are in your home folder, /home/foo, it gets displayed as `~`; at least it is on my computer. this command is using bash string substitutions to escape the slashes in `$HOME` so we get `\/home\/foo` and then in turn using that as a regex to replace that pattern in `$PWD` with a literal `~` ... and then a bunch of escapes are added on top to make it work as an alias in a double-quoted string.

Now when you type `histoff` you get a title change for incognito mode and your history is stopped for that session in that window (the word `histoff` is still logged but nothing after). If you then type `histon` it reverts the title and all of the lines after `histoff` up to and including the line with `histon` are not logged but everything after `histon` is logged.

Example:

```
## this is still logged
histoff  

## this is NOT logged
echo "my password is: password";
fake_ua='If firefox and curl had a child, would it be named furl?';
curl -A "$fake_ua" https://www.itsnotap0rnsiteipromise.com/curvy-girlz/;

vi ~/Documents/maths/super-secret-squirrel/gift-ideas.txt

## this is still NOT logged
histon

## this is logged again
sudo apt install -y kmag;
```