# Installing git "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Tags: command-line, centos, apt, yum, git

I am trying to install git. I run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install git-core git-gui git-doc`

But receive the following error: 
`sudo: apt-get: command not found`

What should I do?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I think it is `2.6.9-023stab048.6-enterprise #1 SMP`

Comment: Sorry it is `CentOS release 5.2 (Final)`

Comment: CentOS uses [`yum`](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: so what should I do? what is the comand I should use?

Answer (score 66):

Since you're using CentOS 5, the default *package manager* is `yum`, not `apt-get`. To install a program using it, you'd normally use the following command:

```
$ sudo yum install <packagename>
```

However, when trying to install git this way, you'll encounter the following error on CentOS 5:

```
$ sudo yum install git
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package git available.
Nothing to do
```

This tells you that the package repositories that `yum` knows about don't contain the required rpms (RPM Package Manager files) to install `git`. This is presumably because CentOS 5 is based on RHEL 5, which was released in 2007, before `git` was considered a mature version control system. To get around this problem, we need to add additional repositories to the list that `yum` uses (We're going to add the RPMforge repository, as per [these instructions](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge?action=show&redirect=Repositories%2FRPMForge#head-b06dd43af4eb366c28879a551701b1b5e4aefccd)).

**This assumes you want the i386 packages. Test by running `uname -i`. If you want the x86_64 packages, replace all occurrences of i386 with x86_64 in the following commands**

First, download the `rpmforge-release` package:

```
$ wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Next, verify and install the package:

```
$ sudo rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
$ rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
$ sudo rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

And now we should be able to install `git`:

```
$ sudo yum install git-gui
```

`yum` will work out the dependencies, and ask you at relevant points if you want to proceed. Press <kbd>y</kbd> for Yes, and <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd> for No.

Comment: It looks like `packages.sw.be` is now dead. Its timing out.

Comment: That's a shame :( If anyone knows anywhere else where that rpm can be obtained from then it'd be great to update the answer, although given CentOS 6 has been around since 2011 and git was available in the default repository this will hopefully become less and less of a problem for people over time.

Comment: I added my build script in an Answer below to build Git from sources. I gave up trying to find trusted sources for third party repos with the package.

Comment: Rpmforge is dead for at least 1 year - https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/issues/375

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a Debian-related distro? If not, you may need to use a different package manager, like YUM (nowadays Red Hat, CentOS, etc.), Portage, Entropy, RPM, etc.

When using a Debian-related distro:

What does it give you?

```
$ command -V apt-get
apt-get is /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Is the binary really there?

```
$ file /usr/bin/apt-get
/usr/bin/apt-get: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm getting `-bash: command: apt-get: not found` for the first one. and `apt-get: ERROR: cannot open `apt-get' (No such file or directory)` for the second.. So what does this mean? that it is not there? is there a replacement? should I add it somehow? how? is there any other way to install git? thanks

Comment: @LucyWeatherford Seems that you're not using a Debian related distro so an easy way to find which distro you are on is to run `lsb_release -a` finding the righ distro you're on will tell you what package manager is available e.g. YUM and RPM if you're using Red Hat or CentOS.

Comment: it is yum, centos. what should I try with yum then?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford Please read [link]http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html you need to understand the basics of managing packages with YUM if your background is APT you will find the equivalences between commands e.g. `apt-get install <package_name>` becomes `yum install <package_name>` be aware that different distros have different package names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to build Git from sources, then the following may help. They are build scripts from [Noloader Github | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). I use them for old OSes, like CentOS 5 and a MIPS ci20 dev board. The distros no longer maintain the repos, so this is the only reliable way to update the software. The scripts are also useful for newer OSes, like Solaris, since Oracle wants you to buy a service contract to get the updates.

Here's the Git script. Its added here to ensure there's some substance to the answer. But you should go back to the GitHub since I modify them on occasion to get the latest release of some packages.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# See fixup for INSTALL_LIBDIR below
INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
INSTALL_LIBDIR="$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib64"

# OpenSSH can only use OpenSSL 1.0.2 at the moment
OPENSSL_TAR=openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
OPENSSL_DIR=openssl-1.0.2l
#OPENSSL_TAR=openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz
#OPENSSL_DIR=openssl-1.1.0e

ZLIB_TAR=zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
ZLIB_DIR=zlib-1.2.11

BZ2_TAR=bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
BZ2_DIR=bzip2-1.0.6

READLN_TAR=readline-7.0.tar.gz
READLN_DIR=readline-7.0

UNISTR_TAR=libunistring-0.9.7.tar.gz
UNISTR_DIR=libunistring-0.9.7

ICONV_TAR=libiconv-1.15.tar.gz
ICONV_DIR=libiconv-1.15

IDN2_TAR=libidn2-0.16.tar.gz
IDN2_DIR=libidn2-0.16

PCRE_TAR=pcre-8.40.tar.gz
PCRE_DIR=pcre-8.40

PCRE2_TAR=pcre2-10.23.tar.gz
PCRE2_DIR=pcre2-10.23

CURL_TAR=curl-7.54.0.tar.gz
CURL_DIR=curl-7.54.0

GIT_TAR=v2.13.0.tar.gz
GIT_DIR=git-2.13.0

# Unset to avoid using an existing trust store when configuring cURL.
# No trust store will be supplied for some OSes, like Solaris.
# Also see '/usr/bin/curl-config --ca' and '/usr/bin/curl-config --configure'
USE_TRUST_STORE=1

###############################################################################

# Autotools on Solaris has an implied requirement for GNU gear. Things fall apart without it.
# Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/partnertech/entry/preparing_for_the_upcoming_removal.
if [[ -d "/usr/gnu/bin" ]]; then
    if [[ ! ("$PATH" == *"/usr/gnu/bin"*) ]]; then
        echo
        echo "Adding /usr/gnu/bin to PATH for Solaris"
        PATH="/usr/gnu/bin:$PATH"
    fi
elif [[ -d "/usr/swf/bin" ]]; then
    if [[ ! ("$PATH" == *"/usr/sfw/bin"*) ]]; then
        echo
        echo "Adding /usr/sfw/bin to PATH for Solaris"
        PATH="/usr/sfw/bin:$PATH"
    fi
elif [[ -d "/usr/ucb/bin" ]]; then
    if [[ ! ("$PATH" == *"/usr/ucb/bin"*) ]]; then
        echo
        echo "Adding /usr/ucb/bin to PATH for Solaris"
        PATH="/usr/ucb/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi

###############################################################################

if [[ -z `which autoreconf` ]]; then
    echo "Some packages require autoreconf. Please install autoconf or automake."
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

if [[ -z `which msgfmt` ]]; then
    echo "Git requires msgfmt. Please install gettext."
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

###############################################################################

echo
echo "If you enter a sudo password, then it will be used for installation."
echo "If you don't enter a password, then ensure INSTALL_PREFIX is writable."
echo "To avoid sudo and the password, just press ENTER and they won't be used."
read -s -p "Please enter password for sudo: " SUDO_PASSWWORD
echo

###############################################################################

THIS_SYSTEM=$(uname -s 2>&1)
IS_DARWIN=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c darwin)
IS_LINUX=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c linux)
IS_CYGWIN=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c cygwin)
IS_MINGW=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c mingw)
IS_OPENBSD=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c openbsd)
IS_DRAGONFLY=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c dragonfly)
IS_FREEBSD=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c freebsd)
IS_NETBSD=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c netbsd)
IS_SOLARIS=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | grep -i -c sunos)

if [[ ("$IS_FREEBSD" -eq "1" || "$IS_OPENBSD" -eq "1" || "$IS_NETBSD" -eq "1" || "$IS_DRAGONFLY" -eq "1" || "$IS_SOLARIS" -eq "1") ]]; then
    if [[ !(-z `which gmake 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no gmake'`) ]]; then
        MAKE=gmake
    else
        MAKE=make
    fi
else
    MAKE=make
fi

# Try to determine 32 vs 64-bit, /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/lib32 and /usr/local/lib64
# The Autoconf programs misdetect Solaris as x86 even though its x64. OpenBSD has
# getconf, but it does not have LONG_BIT.
IS_64BIT=$(getconf LONG_BIT 2>&1 | grep -i -c 64)
if [[ "$IS_64BIT" -eq "0" ]]; then
    IS_64BIT=$(file /bin/ls 2>&1 | grep -i -c '64-bit')
fi

if [[ "$IS_SOLARIS" -eq "1" ]]; then
    SH_KBITS=64
    SH_MARCH=-m64
    INSTALL_LIBDIR="$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib64"
    INSTALL_LIBDIR_DIR="lib64"
elif [[ "$IS_64BIT" -eq "1" ]]; then
    if [[ (-d /usr/lib) && (-d /usr/lib32) ]]; then
        SH_KBITS=64
        SH_MARCH=-m64
        INSTALL_LIBDIR="$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib"
        INSTALL_LIBDIR_DIR="lib"
    elif [[ (-d /usr/lib) && (-d /usr/lib64) ]]; then
        SH_KBITS=64
        SH_MARCH=-m64
        INSTALL_LIBDIR="$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib64"
        INSTALL_LIBDIR_DIR="lib64"
    else
        SH_KBITS=64
        SH_MARCH=-m64
        INSTALL_LIBDIR="$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib"
        INSTALL_LIBDIR_DIR="lib"
    fi
else
    SH_KBITS=32
    SH_MARCH=-m32
    INSTALL_LIBDIR="$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib"
    INSTALL_LIBDIR_DIR="lib"
fi

if [[ -z "$CC" ]]; then CC=`which cc`; fi

MARCH_ERROR=`$CC $SH_MARCH -x c -c -o /dev/null - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -i -c error`
if [[ "$MARCH_ERROR" -ne "0" ]]; then
    SH_MARCH=
fi

echo
echo "********** libdir **********"
echo
echo "Using libdir $INSTALL_LIBDIR"

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** zLib **********"
echo

wget "http://www.zlib.net/$ZLIB_TAR" -O "$ZLIB_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download zLib"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$ZLIB_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$ZLIB_TAR"
cd "$ZLIB_DIR"

SH_LDLIBS=("-ldl -lpthread")
SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure zLib"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build zLib"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Bzip **********"
echo

wget "http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/$BZ2_TAR" -O "$BZ2_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download Bzip"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$BZ2_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$BZ2_TAR"
cd "$BZ2_DIR"

# Fix Bzip install paths
cp Makefile Makefile.orig
sed 's|$(PREFIX)/lib|$(LIBDIR)|g' Makefile.orig > Makefile
rm Makefile.orig
cp Makefile-libbz2_so Makefile-libbz2_so.orig
sed 's|$(PREFIX)/lib|$(LIBDIR)|g' Makefile-libbz2_so.orig > Makefile-libbz2_so
rm Makefile-libbz2_so.orig

# Fix Bzip cpu architecture
cp Makefile Makefile.orig
sed "s|CFLAGS=|CFLAGS=$SH_MARCH |g" Makefile.orig > Makefile
cp Makefile Makefile.orig
sed "s|CXXFLAGS=|CXXFLAGS=$SH_MARCH |g" Makefile.orig > Makefile
rm Makefile.orig
cp Makefile-libbz2_so Makefile-libbz2_so.orig
sed "s|CFLAGS=|CFLAGS=$SH_MARCH |g" Makefile-libbz2_so.orig > Makefile-libbz2_so
cp Makefile-libbz2_so Makefile-libbz2_so.orig
sed "s|CXXFLAGS=|CXXFLAGS=$SH_MARCH |g" Makefile-libbz2_so.orig > Makefile-libbz2_so
rm Makefile-libbz2_so.orig

# Add RPATH
cp Makefile Makefile.orig
sed "s|LDFLAGS=|LDFLAGS=$SH_MARCH -Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR -L$INSTALL_LIBDIR|g" Makefile.orig > Makefile
rm Makefile.orig
cp Makefile-libbz2_so Makefile-libbz2_so.orig
sed "s|LDFLAGS=|LDFLAGS=$SH_MARCH -Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR -L$INSTALL_LIBDIR|g" Makefile-libbz2_so.orig > Makefile-libbz2_so
rm Makefile-libbz2_so.orig

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build Bzip"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install PREFIX="$INSTALL_PREFIX" LIBDIR="$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Unistring **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/$UNISTR_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$UNISTR_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$UNISTR_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$UNISTR_TAR"
cd "$UNISTR_DIR"

SH_LDLIBS=("-ldl -lpthread")
SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Readline **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/$READLN_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$READLN_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download Readline"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$READLN_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$READLN_TAR"
cd "$READLN_DIR"

SH_LDLIBS=("-ldl" "-lpthread")
SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure Readline"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build Readline"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** iConvert **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/$ICONV_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$ICONV_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download iConvert"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$ICONV_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$ICONV_TAR"
cd "$ICONV_DIR"

SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
SH_LDLIBS=("-ldl" "-lpthread")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure iConvert"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build iConvert"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** IDN2 **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/$IDN2_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$IDN2_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$IDN2_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$IDN2_TAR"
cd "$IDN2_DIR"

if [[ "$IS_SOLARIS" -eq "1" ]]; then
    cp src/idn2.c src/idn2.c.orig
    sed '/^#include "error.h"/d' src/idn2.c.orig > src/idn2.c
    cp src/idn2.c src/idn2.c.orig
    sed '43istatic void error (int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...);' src/idn2.c.orig > src/idn2.c
    rm src/idn2.c.orig

    echo "" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "static void" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "error (int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...)" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "{" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "  va_list args;" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "  va_start(args, format);" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "  vfprintf(stderr, format, args);" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "  va_end(args);" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "  exit(status);" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "}" >> src/idn2.c
    echo "" >> src/idn2.c
fi

SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
SH_LDLIBS=("-ldl" "-lpthread")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build IDN"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** OpenSSL **********"
echo

# wget on Ubuntu 16 cannot validate against Let's Encrypt certificate
wget "https://www.openssl.org/source/$OPENSSL_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$OPENSSL_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download OpenSSL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$OPENSSL_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$OPENSSL_TAR"
cd "$OPENSSL_DIR"

# OpenSSL and enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 option
IS_X86_64=$(uname -m 2>&1 | egrep -i -c "(amd64|x86_64)")
if [[ "$SH_KBITS" -eq "32" ]]; then IS_X86_64=0; fi

CONFIG=./config
CONFIG_FLAGS=("no-ssl2" "no-ssl3" "no-comp" "shared" "-DNDEBUG" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR"
        "--prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX" "--openssldir=$INSTALL_PREFIX" "--libdir=$INSTALL_LIBDIR_DIR")
if [[ "$IS_X86_64" -eq "1" ]]; then
    CONFIG_FLAGS+=("enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128")
fi

KERNEL_BITS="$SH_KBITS" "$CONFIG" "${CONFIG_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure OpenSSL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4 depend)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build OpenSSL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install_sw)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** PCRE **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/$PCRE_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$PCRE_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download PCRE"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$PCRE_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$PCRE_TAR"
cd "$PCRE_DIR"

SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
SH_LDLIBS=("-lz" "-ldl" "-lpthread")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --enable-pcregrep-libz --enable-pcregrep-libbz2 \
    --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure PCRE"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4 all)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build PCRE"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** PCRE2 **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/$PCRE2_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$PCRE2_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download PCRE2"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$PCRE2_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$PCRE2_TAR"
cd "$PCRE2_DIR"

SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
SH_LDLIBS=("-lz" "-ldl" "-lpthread")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --enable-pcre2-8 --enable-pcre2-16 --enable-pcre2-32 \
    --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure PCRE2"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4 all)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build PCRE2"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** cURL **********"
echo

# https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=26786
wget "https://curl.haxx.se/download/$CURL_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$CURL_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download cURL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$CURL_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$CURL_TAR"
cd "$CURL_DIR"

SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
SH_LDLIBS=("-lidn2" "-lssl" "-lcrypto" "-lz" "-ldl" "-lpthread")

if [[ ("$IS_SOLARIS" -ne ")" && "$USE_TRUST_STORE" -ne "0") ]]; then
  CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --without-ca-bundle --with-ca-path=/etc/openssl/certs --enable-ipv6 \
    --with-nghttp2 --with-ssl="$INSTALL_PREFIX" \
    --with-libidn2="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"
else
  CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 --with-nghttp2 --with-ssl="$INSTALL_PREFIX" \
    --with-libidn2="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"
fi

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure cURL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4)
"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build cURL"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Git **********"
echo

# wget on Ubuntu 16 cannot validate against DigiCert certificate
wget "https://github.com/git/git/archive/$GIT_TAR" --no-check-certificate -O "$GIT_TAR"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to download Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

rm -rf "$GIT_DIR" &>/dev/null
tar -xzf "$GIT_TAR"
cd "$GIT_DIR"

"$MAKE" configure

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to make configure Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

# "Instruct Git to use pthread library?", http://stackoverflow.com/q/43080417/
for file in $(find `pwd` -iname 'Makefile*')
do 
    cp "$file" "$file.orig"
    sed 's|-lrt|-lrt -lpthread|g' "$file.orig" > "$file"
    rm "$file.orig"
done

# Various Solaris 11 workarounds
if [[ "$IS_SOLARIS" -eq "1" ]]; then
    for file in $(find `pwd` -iname 'Makefile*')
    do 
        cp "$file" "$file.orig"
        sed 's|-lsocket|-lnsl -lsocket|g' "$file.orig" > "$file"
        cp "$file" "$file.orig"
        sed 's|/usr/ucb/install|install|g' "$file.orig" > "$file"
        rm "$file.orig"
    done
    for file in $(find `pwd` -iname 'config*')
    do 
        cp "$file" "$file.orig"
        sed 's|-lsocket|-lnsl -lsocket|g' "$file.orig" > "$file"
        cp "$file" "$file.orig"
        sed 's|/usr/ucb/install|install|g' "$file.orig" > "$file"
        rm "$file.orig"
    done
fi

if [[ -e /usr/local/bin/perl ]]; then
    SH_PERL=/usr/local/bin/perl
elif [[ -e /usr/bin/perl ]]; then
    SH_PERL=/usr/bin/perl
else
    SH_PERL=perl
fi

SH_LDFLAGS=("$SH_MARCH" "-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_LIBDIR" "-L$INSTALL_LIBDIR")
SH_LDLIBS=("-lssl" "-lcrypto" "-lz" "-ldl" "-lpthread")

CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALL_PREFIX/include -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" CXXFLAGS="$SH_MARCH" \
    LDFLAGS="${SH_LDFLAGS[@]}" LIBS="${SH_LDLIBS[@]}" \
    ./configure --enable-pthreads --with-lib="$INSTALL_LIBDIR" --with-openssl="$INSTALL_PREFIX" \
    --with-curl="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --with-libpcre="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --with-zlib="$INSTALL_PREFIX" \
    --with-iconv="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --with-perl="$SH_PERL" --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX"

if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to configure Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

# See INSTALL for the formats and the requirements
MAKE_FLAGS=(-j 4 all)
if [[ ! -z `which asciidoc 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no asciidoc'` ]]; then
    if [[ ! -z `which makeinfo 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no makeinfo'` ]]; then
        MAKE_FLAGS+=("man")
    fi
    if [[ ! -z `which xmlto 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no xmlto'` ]]; then
        MAKE_FLAGS+=("info" "html")
    fi
fi

"$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"

if [[ "$?" -eq "1" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to build Git"
    [[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 1 || return 1
fi

# See INSTALL for the formats and the requirements
MAKE_FLAGS=(install)
if [[ ! -z `which asciidoc 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no asciidoc'` ]]; then
    if [[ ! -z `which makeinfo 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no makeinfo'` ]]; then
        MAKE_FLAGS+=("install-man")
    fi
    if [[ ! -z `which xmlto 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'no xmlto'` ]]; then
        MAKE_FLAGS+=("install-info" "install-html")
    fi
fi

if [[ ! (-z "$SUDO_PASSWWORD") ]]; then
    echo "$SUDO_PASSWWORD" | sudo -S "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
else
    "$MAKE" "${MAKE_FLAGS[@]}"
fi

cd ..

###############################################################################

echo
echo "********** Cleanup **********"
echo

# Set to false to retain artifacts
if true; then

    ARTIFACTS=("$OPENSSL_TAR" "$OPENSSL_DIR" "$UNISTR_TAR" "$UNISTR_DIR" "$READLN_TAR" "$READLN_DIR"
            "$PCRE_TAR" "$PCRE_DIR" "$PCRE2_TAR" "$PCRE2_DIR" "$ZLIB_TAR" "$ZLIB_DIR"  "$BZ2_TAR" "$BZ2_DIR"
            "$IDN2_TAR" "$IDN2_DIR" "$ICONV_TAR" "$ICONV_DIR" "$CURL_TAR" "$CURL_DIR" "$GIT_TAR" "$GIT_DIR")

    for artifact in "${ARTIFACTS[@]}"; do
        rm -rf "$artifact"
    done

    # ./build-git.sh 2>&1 | tee build-git.log
    if [[ -e build-git.log ]]; then
        rm build-git.log
    fi
fi

[[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && exit 0 || return 0
```

***IF*** you decide to use the `sudo` password, then consider [temporarily disabling Bash history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10922/56041) so the password is not logged. I disable histories so I don't accidentally log sensitive information, so its not a problem for me.