# How to print password protected pdf with cups from command line?

Tags: printing, pdf, cups

I have a `*.pdf` file that is password protected. I have the password and I can view the pdf with `mupdf`. However, printing with `CUPS` via `lpr -P PRINTERNAME *.pdf` does not work. All my printing is done via the command line and cups `lpr` command and I don’t want to change that. Is there a way to have `CUPS` print password protected pdfs?

Comment: you can try and save the file to a temp file w/o the password.

Comment: Yes, but I’m also interested in a direct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not remove the password temporary and print the resulting unsecure pdf with `lpr`:

```
pdftk secure.pdf input_pw own output - | lpr
```

If you don't want that this command is listed in bash command history:

```
set +x history
<commands>
set -x history
```

OR

```
<whitespace><command>
```

OR use a script ([adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923893/3739455)):

```
#!/bin/bash
unset password
prompt="Enter Password:"
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char; do
    [[ $char == $'\0' ]] && break
    prompt='*'
    password+="$char"
done
pdftk secure.pdf input_pw "$password" output - | lpr
```

[Source for disabling bash history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10923/72471)

Comment: That is exactly what I did to be honest given that I needed the document printed urgently. But the purist in me wants to know if there is a way without taking the detour. But given that within a few days no other solution turns up I take it that none exists and accept your answer.

Comment: Ah well, yeah I haven't found or know of any other solution. `man lpr` doesn't give us any option, too. Darn.